# Multiply select value from QUERY

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have created a named range called `coins` and have the following query:

```
=QUERY(coins,"SELECT C WHERE A = '"&B17&"' ")
```

which returns the correct values. If I want to multiply this number by e.g. `2` and write the following:

```
=QUERY(coins,"SELECT C*2 WHERE A = '"&B17&"' ")
```

my cell is replaced with `product(2())` and the correct value is placed at the underneath cell.

I have tried also:

```
=QUERY(coins,"SELECT product(C,2) WHERE A = '"&B17&"' ")
```

but had no correct result.

How do I get the value of the multiplication on that specific cell and not the one underneath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this:

```
=QUERY(coins, "SELECT C*2 WHERE A = '"&B17&"' label C*2''")
```

Comment: what label do I input if I have the following arithmetic operation

 `=QUERY(coins, "SELECT " &C2&"/B*C*D WHERE A = '"&D2&"'  ")`

Comment: `label "&C2&"/B*C*D ''`